# can't delete folder from batch - folder or file open in another program

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-directory

done a search on this, but little joy. I am making and later, trying to delete a folder in the same batch file:

```
mkdir "%_gameKey%"
:: Stuff.....
rmdir /s /q "%_gameKey%"
```

I get the error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." I also can't delete the folder via right-click delete - same error. Interestingly, the rmdir removes the contents of the folder. There is nothing in the folder, nor is there anything obvious accessing it.

I have used Unlocker - shows no processes. Have also used Process Explorer, searched on the folder name (with/without full path) - no search results.

When I restart my machine, I can delete it. Not sure if down to user permissions. I see from this that Users only have Read/write not full control. (sorry - not very good with user permissions stuff - especially on windows!). However - surely it can't be this as I can delete it upon restart.

The folder is on a non OS drive.

I'm stumped - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A folder cannot be deleted on Windows if any application uses this folder currently as working directory.

In your case I suppose that the batch file uses command `cd` to change the working directory to the created directory. So you need to use `cd` once again to set a different working directory before using command `rmdir` to delete this directory.

It is of course no good idea to start other applications with working directory being currently the directory which should be deleted later and which continue running on exit of batch file as those started applications have this directory as working directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, after launched a powershell process from a folder via win cmd.
After powershell finished, I `cd ..` in win CMD but `rd /q /s` gave error: *open in another process*
I get same error when manually delete folder in explorer window, even if it was empty.

`wmic process` revealed that powershell.exe could be locking the folder, even though powershell had finished the task & powershell window had closed.
This was confirmed by `tasklist`

I then `taskkill /im powershell.exe`, after which the folder could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My word - that was an obscure one, but finally found the answer by stepping through the code putting the rmdir in various places. I post this here in case anyone encounters the same...

Basically, I was calling cmd prompts and launching external exe's whilst in the said folder. Later, I was forcibly closing the exe's with TaskKill, but this was leaving the cmd consoles open at the path of the directory I was trying to delete. I'll try be clearer....

Whilst batch script was in the directory (e.g. C:\Windows\Scripts\Launch), I used the following command:

```
Start "AppLaunch" Call "!_supExe!" !_supCmd!
```

Which, after expansion, translated to, for e.g.:

```
Start "AppLaunch" Call "C:\Windows\Program Files(x86)\Troubleshooter\trbshtr.exe" -game "My Game"
```

I was using this because, from reading, there appears to be a bug in windows making the following command fail:

```
Start "AppLaunch" "C:\Windows\Program Files(x86)\Troubleshooter\trbshtr.exe" -game "My Game"
```

The problem comes when you have to use quotes for both the exe and the parameters (for instance where there's spaces). Windows doesn't read it right. Thus had to use topmost to launch these apps.

Problem being, when used:

```
taskkill /f /im trbshtr.exe
```

The exe was killed, but the command prompt wasn't. Using /b on the Start command made no difference.

So, the solution was - cd out of the directory into one that the batch script doesn't alter before launching the other apps via the above. Job done....

Now that just leaves me with how to close all those opened cmd windows (or those in taskmgr if I use the /b switch). That's probably a topic for another search or thread!